# Use a variable as the list of arguments to a function

Tags: cmake

I want to pass a variable's value to a function as if I had directly written it. Here is what I have tried:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)
project(test)

message(WARNING "This is a warning")
# CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:4 (message):
#   This is a warning

set(variable "WARNING \"This is a warning\"")
message(${variable})
# WARNING "This is a warning"
```

Unfortunately, you can see that the second call to `message` doesn't behave like the first one. How to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Why not just make the warning message itself a variable and then print out with `message(WARNING ${message_var})`?

Comment: @DeveloperPaul Because this was just a minimal example for something more complex that I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign a list to the variable:

```
set(variable WARNING "This is a warning")
```

Alternatively, as elements in a list are actually separated with a **semicolon**:

```
set(variable "WARNING;This is a warning")
```